# jQuery UI slider to control youtube volume

Tags: jquery, api, jquery-ui, youtube, youtube-api

I have been having a lot of troubles with this and I was wondering if anyone on here could help me out.

I'm using the jQuery youtube player plugin found here: http://badsyntax.github.com/jquery-youtube-player/ and am trying to create a simple slider to use for the volume.

I managed to create a button that reduces the volume by editing the jquery.youtube.player.js file and adding

```
volume : function(){
        this.youtubePlayer.setVolume(30);
    },
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [setVolume(int)](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/js_api_reference.html#Playback_controls) is not a method from the plugin, it's from the youtube player api.
To use it you need to select the youtube dom object:

```
$('.youtube-player-video object').get(0).setVolume(ui.value);
```

Also see [your updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ECbF3/93/).

Answer (score 2):

I do not know the jquery Plugin. But there is no volume function described in there examples so i can not see how this should work.

Also the this in

```
this.youtubePlayer.setVolume(ui.value);
```

And why are you using `$(function() {});` and `(function($){})(this.jQuery);`
They are more or less equal so you could put your code together...